# Import Arabic Wordnet in python

Tags: python, arabic, wordnet

i need to do function on arabic words by using python..
and i need to link arabic wordnet with python to do some method like :

```
wn.synset('جميل')
```

i find Multilingual Lexicons: AWN - ArabicWN

```
http://www.talp.upc.edu/index.php/technology/resources/multilingual-lexicons-and-machine-translation-resources/multilingual-lexicons/72-awn
```

and i try to run :
A set of basic python functions for accessing the database

```
http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/awn/AWNDatabaseManagement.py.gz
```

but when run the code(AWNDatabaseManagement.py) 
this error occur:

```
processing file  E:/usuaris/horacio/arabicWN/AWNdatabase/upc_db.xml
file  E:/usuaris/horacio/arabicWN/AWNdatabase/upc_db.xml  not correct

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/s/Desktop/arab", line 403, in <module>
    wn.compute_index_w()
NameError: global name 'wn' is not defined
```

any idea?

Comment: where does 'wn' come from? there should be a directive like 'import wordnet as wn'

Comment: global name 'wn' is defined inside the file (AWNDatabaseManagement.py)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AWNDatabaseManagement.py` should be fed by the argument `-i` that has the Arabic WordNet as a value. If the argument is not specified, it will use a default path `E:/usuaris/horacio/arabicWN/AWNdatabase/upc_db.xml`.

So to resolve that, download [the xml database of Arabic WordNet](http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/awn/get_bd.php) `upc_db.xml` . I suggest to place it in the same folder with the script `AWNDatabaseManagement.py`. Then,run:

```
$ python AWNDatabaseManagement.py -i upc_db.xml
```

This what I got after running it, no errors:

```
processing file  upc_db.xml
<open file 'upc_db.xml', mode 'r' at 0xb74689c0>
```

You can also change the line 320

```
opts['i']='E:/usuaris/horacio/arabicWN/AWNdatabase/upc_db.xml'
```

to

```
opts['i']='upc_db.xml'
```

and then run the script without `-i`

You can load it:

```
>> from AWNDatabaseManagement import wn
```

if it fails, check that you are putting the xml resource in the right path.

---

Now to get something like `wn.synset('جميل')`. Arabic Wordnet has a function `wn.get_synsets_from_word(word)`, but it gives offsets. Also it accepts the words only as vocalized in the database. For example, you should use `جَمِيل` not `جميل`:

```
>> wn.get_synsets_from_word(u"جَمِيل")
[(u'a', u'300218842')]
```

`300218842` is the offset of the synset of جميل . I suggest to use the next method instead. list words by:

```
 >> for word,ids  in sorted(wn.get_words(False)):
 ..     print word, ids
```

you will get a result like this:

```
 جَمِيعَة [u'jamiyEap_1']
 جَمِيل [u'jamiyl_1']
 جَمِيْعَة [u'jamiyoEap_1']
 جَمَّدَ [u'jam~ada_2', u'jam~ada_1']
```

Choose your word, and pick an id of its ids. IDs are written in [Buckwalter romanization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckwalter_transliteration). Many ids means the word has different meanings. Describe the chosen word by:

```
>> wn._words["jamiyl_1"].describe()
wordid  jamiyl_1
value  جَمِيل
synsets  [u'jamiyl_a1AR']
forms  [(u'root', u'\u062c\u0645\u0644')]
```

Now you have the synsets list. For more information about a synset, use:

```
>> wn._items["jamiyl_a1AR"].describe()
itemid  jamiyl_a1AR
offset  300218842
name  جَمِيل
type  synset
pos  a
input links  [[u'be_in_state', u'jamaAl_n1AR'], [u'near_antonym', u'qabiyH_a1AR']]
output links  [[u'near_antonym', u'qabiyH_a1AR']]
```

Comment: so no way to use words Without Harkat/Tashkeel? in http://sourceforge.net/projects/javasourcecodeapiarabicwordnet/files/latest/download :There two ways to use API Java code
1- With Harkat/Tashkeel
In the main method in main class write
AWN awn=new AWN (XMLfilepath,true);
2- Without Harkat/Tashkeel
In this way the code will remove the „Harkat/Tashkeel‟ from the source XML file and from the user input In the main method in main class write
AWN awn=new AWN (XMLfilepath,false);
Where XMLfilepath is the path to the XML source in your computer.... what about python?

Comment: @Mona The python API  is not complete , but it should have a wrap up to surpass the vocalization. I think you should ask another question for this, so I (or anyone else) can give a clean answer.