# Arabic Word Net synonyms in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, arabic

I am using python 2.7, I am trying to get synonyms of Arabic words using Arabic WordNet

I downloaded both needed files:

1. [AWNDatabaseManagement.py](http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/awn/AWNDatabaseManagement.py.gz)
2. [upc_db.xml](http://www.talp.upc.edu/index.php/technology/resources/multilingual-lexicons-and-machine-translation-resources/multilingual-lexicons/72-awn)

**Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29545179/1327005), I made few edits in AWNDatabaseManagement.py:**

1. line 320 is `opts['i']='upc_db.xml'` instead of

   opts['i']='E:/usuaris/horacio/arabicWN/AWNdatabase/upc_db.xml'
2. I added that at the end `wn.get_synsets_from_word(u"جَمِيل")`
3. I added that at line 2: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Then I ran it using: `$ python AWNDatabaseManagement.py -i  upc_db.xml` and no errors were found: `<open file 'upc_db.xml', mode 'r' at 0x10156c270>`

Yet when I run my original py file:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
jan = wn.synsets('wait')[0]
print(jan) #this works fine
print(jan.lemma_names(lang='arb')) #this works fine

wn.get_synsets_from_word(u"جَمِيل")
```

I get :

```
`Synset('delay.n.01') [u'\u0627\u0650\u0646\u0652\u062a\u0650\u0638\u0627\u0631', u'\u062a\u0623\u062c\u0650\u064a\u0644', u'\u062a\u0623\u062e\u0650\u064a\u0631', u'\u062a\u0648\u0642\u0651\u064f\u0641'] Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects20Dec.py" line 492, in <module> wn.get_synsets_from_word("جَمِيل") AttributeError: 'WordNetCorpusReader' object has no attribute 'get_synsets_from_word`
```

I really don't know what is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arabic Wordnet works independent of nltk. In the folder where you have `AWNDatabaseManagement.py` and `upc_db.xml`, put your script and change it to:

```
from AWNDatabaseManagement import wn
synsets = wn.get_synsetids_from_word(u"جَمِيل")
for s in synsets:
    wn._items[s].describe()
```

Output will be:

```
itemid  jamiyl_a1AR
offset  300218842
name  جَمِيل
type  synset
pos  a
input links  [[u'be_in_state', u'jamaAl_n1AR'], [u'near_antonym', u'qabiyH_a1AR']]
output links  [[u'near_antonym', u'qabiyH_a1AR']]
```

Comment: @I.Abdelsalam This is not unicode, its the ID of synset group, check my updated code and consider the AWN is not developed well to give results clean.