# Arabic Word Net synonyms in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I try to find answer for my Question in [Arabic Word Net synonyms in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820968/arabic-word-net-synonyms-in-python?lq=1) but there is an error related to 
 File "C:\Arabic Ontology paper\AWN\AWNDatabaseManagement.py", line 54
    return filter(lambda(x):(x[0]==type) or (type=='all'),self._links_in)
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

you should remove parentheses of x,

use `"lambda x"` instead of `"lambda(x)"`